# Skipping the first two rows of an excel spread sheet while writing to it

Tags: c#, epplus

I have this method that writes data to my excel spreadsheet. I will like to skip the first 2 rows
before writing out the data. The first two rows contains headers. How can I skip the first 2 rows ?

```
            public ExcelWorksheet WriteToExcelWorksheet(ExcelPackage package, IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> data)
            {
                var rows = data.ToList();
                var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];

                for (var r = 0; r < rows.Count; r++)
                {
                    var row = rows[r].ToList();
                    for (var c = 0; c < row.Count; c++)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row[c]))
                        {
                            if (decimal.TryParse(row[c], out var d))
                            {
                                ws.Cells[r + 1, c + 1].Value = d;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ws.Cells[r + 1, c + 1].Value = row[c];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return ws;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply start writing rows accordingly :)

So in this line for example:

```
ws.Cells[r + 1, c + 1].Value = d;
```

make

```
ws.Cells[r + 3, c + 1].Value = d;
```

having:

```
public ExcelWorksheet WriteToExcelWorksheet(ExcelPackage package, IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> data)
{
    var rows = data.ToList();
    var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];

    for (var r = 0; r < rows.Count; r++)
    {
        var row = rows[r].ToList();
        for (var c = 0; c < row.Count; c++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row[c]))
            {
                if (decimal.TryParse(row[c], out var d))
                {
                    ws.Cells[r + 3, c + 1].Value = d;
                }
                else
                {
                    ws.Cells[r + 3, c + 1].Value = row[c];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return ws;
}
```

Comment: That does not work. It affects the data. It is skipping the data instead not the rows

Comment: I don't understand. You wrote: "I will like to skip the first 2 rows before writing out the data" so what exactly you want to achieve, because i am kind a loss :)

Comment: I don't want to skip the data, I want to skip few rows which happens to be headers in my excel spread sheet. when i do r = 2, it is skipping the first 2 rows in my data which is wrong.

Comment: And who and where putted this headers there? Where is the code responsible for it?

Comment: I am making a copy of the excel file stored on a server and writing to it. I created the excel file as a template with headers on the first 2 rows

Comment: Works great. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Happy to hear :) If I did help - please mark the answer as a solution ;)